# Struct variable name prefixed with a .(dot) need explaination

Tags: c++

This is an extract of code from [OBS Studio under GitHub](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/master/plugins/obs-ffmpeg/obs-ffmpeg-audio-encoders.c). I failed to understand the followings:

1) Is the struct keyword followed by a struct name (obs_encoder_info) and a tag(opus_encoder_info) ?

2) How a struct variable can be prefixed with a .(dot) ? Is it a member variable of another struct?

```
struct obs_encoder_info opus_encoder_info = {
   .id             = "ffmpeg_opus",
   .type           = OBS_ENCODER_AUDIO,
   .codec          = "opus",
   .get_name       = opus_getname,
   .create         = opus_create,
   .destroy        = enc_destroy
};
```

Comment: That's officially the weirdest C++ code I've ever seen. If I didn't read the accepted answer already, I'd be really surprised that even compiles in C++. I really need to catch up on C++20.

Comment: The link is to a file whose extension is ".c". The code uses the `struct` keyword to declare a variable whose type is a `struct`. These are indicators of C, rather than C++. Are you sure this should have been tagged c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) (since C++20).

So it declares an object named `opus_encoder_info` with type `obs_encoder_info`, and its data member `id` is initialized with value `"ffmpeg_opus"`, `type` is initialized with value `OBS_ENCODER_AUDIO`, and so on.

Comment: It was valid in C language. Is it allowed only since C++20? Thanks

Comment: @ark1974 Yes, from the point view of the c++ standard. I know that some compilers have supported the syntax from long ago. And note that the features suppored by c  and c++ are not identical.

Comment: Is this answer accurate for this question? I looked at the linked source file, and to me it looks more like C99 than C++20.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is the struct keyword followed by a struct name (obs_encoder_info) and a tag(opus_encoder_info) ?

Almost. The `struct` keyword is followed by a struct name, but after that is a variable (not tag) name. This line declares (and initializes) `opus_encoder_info` as a variable whose type is `struct obs_encoder_info`. (In C++ the `struct` keyword is not required, but in C it is.)

> 2) How a struct variable can be prefixed with a .(dot) ? Is it a member variable of another struct?

Your terminology is a bit off here, as the struct variable is `opus_encoder_info` while the things prefixed with a dot are struct members. In any event, a `struct obs_encoder_info` apparently has members named `id`, `type`, etc., and those fields of the `opus_encoder_info` variable are being initialized via [initialization by designators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization), which was a new feature of C99. (In brief, member `x` is initialized to value `a` by writing `.x = a` inside the braces.)

Yes, I am answering as if the code was written in C even though this question is tagged "C++". I justify that because I have reason to believe the code in question is C. First, there is the use of the `struct` keyword when declaring a variable – required in C, but superfluous in C++. Second, the code came from a file whose extension is ".c", not ".C" (capitalized) or ".cpp" or any other extension indicating a C++ source file. Third, this kind of code existed in [the file in 2014](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/cabe98cb4e821c4e4a6bce18c3e05294a4690a98/plugins/obs-ffmpeg/obs-ffmpeg-aac.c) (there was a name change in 2017), which is rather early to use a C++20 feature, much less use it in production code.

So I have concluded that this question is mis-tagged. However, the presence of an answer (and an accepted answer at that) means that fixing the question's tag could cause more confusion than it would resolve.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying +1. Yes I want to discuss in the context of C++ only as the matter is already supported in C.  So, will the code work with C++99 or C++20 is essential is the contention.

Comment: @ark1974 It is rather odd to present code written in one language and ask what it means in another. Odder yet to not even mention that the source is a different language. Are you intentionally trying to confuse people?